# Foreign Keyboards and Mathematica?

Tags: formatting, input-devices

I have a foreign language keyboard (French). Most of my programs recognize the my French keyboard, **except** Mathematica, which behaves as if the keyboard were English. So far I haven't found any way to change this.

Unfortunately, French and English keyboards are **significantly** different. For example, the non-letter keys have basically no overlap--it took me about 10 minutes to find the colon key.

Does anyone know how to get *Mathematica* to recognize a non-English keyboard?

---

Edit: Operating system is Windows 7.

Comment: I guess the name of your operating system might be relevant.

Comment: Okay, duh. Sorry about that. Windows 7.

Comment: I hope you find a solution to this problem. In any case I recommend you to get a second keyboard just for programming with an American English layout. Not only for the easy access to all those characters needed for programming but also to get keyboard shortcuts that make sense in most programming tools.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 5, WRI has provided a [French Language Kit](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/BySubject/Mathematica/ApplicationPackages/WolframResearchApps/MathematicaFrenchLanguageKit/) for *Mathematica*.
This is an add-on which adds French documentation, user interface, and spell checking.

If you download and install the linked package, you should be able to set *Mathematica* to use French in the Preferences dialog.

Additionally, make sure your keyboard layout is set to the use the proper keymap for your (French) keyboard. Here are [instructions for changing keymaps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/258824) in Windows.